# how to programatically delete the first 3 rows in a table?

Tags: ms-access, vba

Is there a way to programatically delete the first 3 rows in an Access table? I need to perform this delete operation after I have finsihed importing an excel file into Access.

Comment: Rows don't have an intrinsic order in tables, so *first three* by itself is meaningless. What does *first three* mean to you here? The rows that have the earliest timestamp? The rows with the lowest ID numbers? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

Execute the SQL statement below from your code.

```
DELETE FROM TableName
WHERE TableNameId IN (SELECT TOP 3 TableNameId FROM TableName)
```

Please replace `TableName` and `TableNameId` with the name of the table you want to delete rows and the identifier column respectively.

Note that you can't execute this statement directly. You must use the available objects on Access to perform SQL queries / operations.

Comment: Please, if you think my answer helped you and you consider that is the correct answer in this case, mark it as accepted.